# How to display unicode character in excel textbox?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I'm using Microsoft Forms 2.0 TextBox and trying to display Myanmar Unicode on it. I've tried to set Properties->Font to Myanmar3 (Myanmar Unicode font). The characters are visible when typing or has focus in the textbox before saving the excel file.

[image: textbox with unicode entered]

But after focus out from the textbox, they are displayed as question marks.

[image: characters convert to question marks]

How can I display the characters correctly?

- I'm using Windows 7 (Myanmar Language is not officially supported in this windows version yet)
- I'm using Office 2010 and VBA 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Richtext Editor (Developer -> Insert -> More Controls -> 'MSREdit Class').
Now displaying the characters is ok but -

- Saving the excel file with Myanmar characters in RichTextbox and
  re-open the file still rendering the characters as question marks. I
  have to clear the RichTextbox with code before closing worksheet to
  be able to work well next time.
- Viewing RichTextbox's properties and focus out of it causes the excel to force close sometime.